# Set firestore object if it does not exist

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm in the situation where a firebase write wakes up a cloud function.
Inside the cloud functions I perform a `.set()`.

My issue is, that cloud functions garantes an `at least once` policy. Instead of an `exactly one policy`. That means, it sometimes happens that multiple functions wake up and write to the exact same spot.

I know I can use a transaction, and ask "does document already exist", if not, don't do anything. But I was wondering, if there is a flag, that says `set("data", exist=false)` or so.

So far I could not find anything in the documentation. And I was hoping I could avoid the extra `.get()` for end-user latency reasons.

Keep in mind, cloud functions use the admin-sdk. That means, security rules can't be used as a solution.

Comment: If your writes are idempotent, this shouldn't really matter. The duplicate executions should be pretty rare.

Comment: I know. But sadly I need a random value when create/set the data. I guess transaction is the only reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want is possible without a transaction.

Interestingly enough, the inverse *is* possible: using `update()` you can allow a write only when the document already exists.

As you've already said: usually this type of condition should be caught in security rules. But since Cloud Functions uses the Admin SDK to perform its writes, it bypasses those rules.

Comment: Yes exactly. The inverse exists in update. So I was hoping I'm simply missing it, or it's not documented.